# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth for UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uilabel, uitextview

adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth seems to work just great for UILabels, but I'm now using a UITextView and the options doesn't appear to exist.

I'm on the latest Xcode and Swift 5.

They seem to have enabled it for UITextField, too, as per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619625-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

Another question is, what would be the benefit of using UITextView over UILabel? I can change all text views to labels if need me.

All the "answers" I have found seem to be for Swift 3

Comment: If you found solutions in Swift 3, what's preventing you from using them?

Comment: If you don't need editing or text selection, then you can use UILabel

Comment: UITextView has a scroll view built in.

Comment: @Alex More correctly, a text view is a scroll view.

Comment: Thanks Guys, right now I don't believe I need a scroll view so I'll move to UILabels until such time as I need to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments on my OP lead me to use UILabel over UITextView. UILabel has the ability to change text size if the text is too big for the constraints.

To do this for UILabel you use:

```
proText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

The benefits and features of UITextView (editing, text selection and scroll view to name a few) were not required for what I need.